# Can a Filipino citizen with no Korean visa with a long layover in Seoul take the airport free city tour?

Tags: transit

I am a Filipino citizen traveling from Saipan to Manila via Seoul, with 13 hours layover.  Do I need a Korean visa to take the airport free city tour?

Comment: @Dorothy indeed, nice catch.  I've voted to close.